# How to retrieve and update data from database using Dialogflow chat bot

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am very new to api.ai(Dialogflow). In my scenario i have to create a chat bot who should be able to update customer information in the real time database by taking the input from customer.
I am not sure how to do this. By some research i understood either by writing code in firebase function it is possible or by writing webhook and deploying to server.

But i am not understanding how to write the code. Any one can give any suggestions or any reference so that i can start coding.

I tried to write by seeing the weather webhook but did not understand this.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can u try this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/assistant-codelab/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Comment: I have tried this too but in this the database can be store as json forrmat but in my case database is the payment details. So how can i make it json and use? and how it ll send the updated value back to the real db